# Assembly using BEQ? (I use MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips

extremely newbie coder here, especially to assembly language and I'm in need of some help. I'm afraid.

Basically I have to write a program of a basic 4 function calculator and use conditional statements.

Is BEQ even considered a conditional statement? lol..

The display looks like this

```
Welcome to the 4 function calculator
1 - Addition
2 - Sub
3 - Mult
4 - Div
9 - Exit
```

If you push 1 then this is the sample output

```
1
Please enter a number: 3
Please enter a number: 4
Please enter a number: 5
The sum of 3, 4, and 5 is 12

Welcome to the 4 function calculator
1 - Addition
2 - Sub
3 - Mult
4 - Div
9 - Exit
```

So that's the basic skeleton of what's supposed to happen.

I KNOW how to get it using beq, the only part I'm struggling with is the error msgs to throw in.

what function or the phrase do I use if the numbers aren't 1, 2 ,3 ,4 or 9?
I'm not sure if it's possible so now I'm not sure if I can actually use beq
What I would need to make it work would be like in c++ `else if (x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3 && x != 4 && x != 9)`  or something along those lines...  I'm not sure how to code all that into assembly as I'm not even sure you can use that many variables in 1 line of coding without having an error.

If I can't use BEQ then what other possibilities can I use?

I was thinking about bgt and blt but it seems to weird to have to use it if the range is only 1 number  ex bgt 0 blt 2 would mean the input has to be 1.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  Just read about bne ... which would mean the program would have to read all 5 bne's before displaying the error.

Comment: _"what function or the phrase do I use if the numbers aren't 1, 2 ,3 ,4 or 9?"_ Why not jump to the appropriate function handler when the number _is_ equal to 1, 2, 3, 4 or 9? Then if none of those jumps were taken you know that the number is something else.

Comment: I haven't implemented Jump yet but to my understanding it just jumps to the function, correct?

If that's so, then I don't see how that affects inputs that aren't 1,2,3,4, and 9?

'beq $t0, 1, Add
j Add?'

Jumps to add function but what if I input 5?

I don't know exactly how to check or ask the program to read if there were no jumps then output that the user didn't input a number listed?  If this is what you're trying to tell me of course..

Comment: _" I don't see how that affects inputs that aren't 1,2,3,4, and 9"_ If you're jumping on condition X being true and the jump isn't taken, then you know that X isn't true.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from.  Makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: There is an absolute great tool to translate C++ to assembler. It is called GCC, and using -S will make the output more readable. I'm not being sarcastic, studying compiler output of simple programs is a great way to quickly get an overall view on asm.